# При вводе некоторых кириллических символов Paths.get принимает их за другие символы

Tags: java

```
public class CLIENT_PATH {

    String PATH;

    Path Path;

    public void INPUT_PATH(){

        out.println("Введите путь");

        do {
            out.print("  ");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            PATH = in.next();

            Path = Paths.get(PATH);

            if (Files.exists(Path)) {
                out.println("    Путь введён\n");
            }
            else
                out.println("    Ошибка");
       } 
        while(Files.notExists(Path));

        out.println(PATH);

    }
}
```

Почему при вводе русских символов К(R), П (G), О(J), и М (V) и возможно других выбрасывает исключение и в ответе пишет что введены совсем другие символы?

> Введите путь
>
> п
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char < ? > at index 0: ?
>
> Введите путь
>
> м
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal
>   char <<> at index 0: <

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку.

Comment: @Pavel В проекте NetBeans стоит UTF-8, кодировку я нигде не менял.

Comment: А в терминалах винды win1251 или вообще  861

Comment: @pavel Где мне тогда поменять кодировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    do {
        try {

            out.print("\n      ");

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            PA = in.next();

            Path PATH = Paths.get(PA);

            if(Files.exists(PATH)) {
                out.print("\n        Adres programm vvedon\n");
            }
            else {
                PA = null;

                out.print("\n        Oshibka\n");
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidPathException E) {
            PA = null;

            out.print("        Oshibka\n");
        }
    }
    while(PA == null);
```